# Annotation does not check a Dict argument correctly

Tags: python, python-typing

I am learning a bit about annotations. I am using Python 3.8.6 and before I dig into the `TypedDict` alternative, I would like to understand why `my_dict()` is accepting a dictionary (`movie`) that has an `int` as value:

```
from typing import Dict

movie = {"name": "Torrente", "year": "1996"}

def my_dict(bla: Dict[str, int]):

    return bla

print(my_dict(movie))
```

Could someone help me to understand this?

Comment: What are you expecting to do the type checking, here? MyPy, for example, _does_ tell you that's not valid: https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10&gist=8ffeded3d95cd70350fadd302021fbb7.

Comment: Wait, did you expect your type annotations to be enforced at runtime? They aren't.

Comment: ah, ok! I was expecting getting an error at runtime, i must use a tool like `mypy`. Thank you guys!

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga , could you put your comment as answer, so that i can mark the post as solved?

Comment: or yours @jonrsharpe, it was also helpful enough

Comment: In that case it's covered by e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/41692473/3001761, https://stackoverflow.com/q/38892779/3001761